# How to manually add OS in GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual booted.. however, I have a partition with Windows 7 which does not have an entry in bootloader. How can I manually edit the GRUB so that I can get Windows 7, 8 as well as Ubuntu?

Comment: if you're able to boot into Ubuntu, open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub` and see if the Windows OS are detected.. if not try using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tools/CD..

Comment: Try this: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/400886/how-can-i-add-a-new-operating-system-boot-entry-to-the-grub2-menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/400886/how-can-i-add-a-new-operating-system-boot-entry-to-the-grub2-menu)

Answer (score -1):

You can Manually edit the Grub configuration easily by following these [Steps](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config),

However, if you have another partition in the same disk or another disk, you can try by @Reparing@ GRUB from the LTS media. Which sholud technically detect the other OS. 
If this doesnt help, only then head to edit the Config.

Comment: please elaborate more about Repairing from LTS Media

Comment: When You boot in from the 12.04 LTS media, It will detect the existing OS and make this entries in GRUB automatically. I.e. Before you choose the installation mode/details etc. If you're confident of the selected OSes you can safely quit this process. Then, remove media and try again. If this doesnot help, simply "Reinstall" - with "retain Home directory". it should fix it