# Doubt while installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

I install ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with ubuntu 14.04.Its shows installation success. But when restarted it automaticlly comes to ubuntu 14.04 ,what will i do?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you installed 16.04 first and then installed 14.04 over top of it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think *along* has to be read like he has 2 installations of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please post [boot-info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) to avoid confusion from answers that assume something that is not present in your installation(s).

Answer (score 2):

If you installed 16.04 after you installed 14.04, it is probable that you are booting of the Grub of the 14.04, which has been installed in the MBR (by default). It does not know of your new 16.04 installation.

Fixing it is not difficult. As you can boot 14.04, you can execute as root:

```
update-grub
```

This should detect both 14.04 and 16.04 (see also [How can I add a new operating system boot entry to the GRUB2 menu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/400890/534682)).

You can then use the instructions in [NZD's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/815217/534682) to change your default operating system.

Answer (score 1):

When you've installed both, one of them will be set up to be the default in GRUB. That is the one that will boot when you power up or reset your system.

When your reboot your system, you can [interrupt GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/a/621395/425630) and select a different OS.

To make it permanent see for instance [How to edit GRUB Default Operating System?](https://askubuntu.com/q/401023/425630) or [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/q/100232/425630).