# I recently dual booted kali linux alongside Ubuntu 18.04.....However I'm not getting any option to select the os......How can i fix it?

Tags: dual-boot

I'm not getting any option to select the OS. The laptop directly boots into Ubuntu (my main OS) even though kali linux is properly installed in about 300 gb. A technical support will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just boot up Ubuntu and run the following command to update your Grub menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then, reboot.

Comment: I assume you mean `sudo update-grub`, but don't you also need `sudo grub-install` afterwards? I haven't used grub in a few years, but you used to.

Comment: @terdon [Here is an example](https://askubuntu.com/a/400890/167115) where the other os is Linux Mint.

Comment: Yes, that isn't the question. `update-grub` will detect installed OSs and will write a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. What I am not completely sure about is whether or not that new file is actually read by grub on boot or if it is copied somewhere by `grub-install`. The old grub (grub1) used to be able to read the file directly and manually editing it would change the menu, but I seem to recall that grub2 does not and you might need the `grub-install` command to make the new config take effect. But, as I said, I'm not sure.

Comment: @terdon Yes, on grub2, changes that I've made to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` have shown up directly on the grub menu after running `grub-install` including any customization or new OS. However, `update-grub` must be run from the OS that installed the current grub menu or the changes will not take effect. The only time I've had to run `grub-install` is to repair or replace a broken grub using [this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot).

Comment: @terdon However, if you were to make changes to the Kali `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, you would need to run `update-grub` and `grub-install` on Kali for the changes to take effect because the current grub is linked to Ubuntu.